# Magento 2 Product grid collection filtering on programmatic Qty column values

Tags: magento2, collection, grid, product-collection, programatically

I am programatically updating the qty column values for configurable products.

Sadly, the grid filter for this column doesn't work with new values.

The underlying catalog product collection joins with cataloginventory_stock_item table for this field, via the **Magento\CatalogInventory\Ui\DataProvider\Product\AddQuantityFieldToCollection** DataProvider field strategy, and since I haven't changed the qty column values inside the database I don't see the correct results.

The filter works if value 0 (which is the default conf products qty value stored in db) is used in filter.

Can I filter the collection for this field based on the programatically calculated values I am displaying in the grid and how exactly?

Is it possible and how can I join on programatic values instead of a db table column?

Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Plugin and add the below code in your admin's di.xml file

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider">
    <plugin name="product-collection-sorting" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\ProductDataProvider" sortOrder="999"/>
</type>
```

Now create file [Vendor][Module]\Plugin\ProductDataProvider

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider as RelatedProductDataProvider;
class ProductDataProvider extends RelatedProductDataProvider
{

public function afterGetData(
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider $subject,
        $result
    ){
        $subject->getCollection()->clear();
        $subject->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', ['eq' => 4])->load();
        $items = $subject->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', ['eq' => 4])->toArray();
        $totalRecords = $subject->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', ['eq' => 4])->load()->getSize();
    }

}
```